# RTSP video link is not playing smoothly in android

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer, rtsp

I am trying to build an android app that will stream video from RTSP web link. I have used vitamio library and video is streaming but the problem is, it is not streaming smoothly. Playback speed changes while streaming.
How to get rid from this?
Code is given below,

```
videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(liveUrl));
videoView.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
videoView.setOnCompletionListener(this);
videoView.setOnCompletionListener(this);
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.start();
videoView.setVideoQuality(-16);
videoView.setBufferSize(2048);
videoView.requestFocus();
```